# error Command "buildpack" not found : m2 PWA

Tags: magento2, pwa, pwa-studio, yarn

I'm trying to setup PWA in ubuntu system as showing in this reference link: [magento PWA](https://magento.github.io/pwa-studio/venia-pwa-concept/setup/)

At this step yarn `buildpack create-custom-origin packages/venia-concept` i'm getting this error:

```
yarn run v1.22.4
error Command "buildpack" not found.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Thanks.

Comment: have you found the solution

Comment: nop, still looking. :(

Comment: This question has been asked a year ago? Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to downgrade your npm version with the below command. After it will work fine.

```
npm install -g npm@6
```